# Store a string in Oracle DB table

Tags: java, oracle

I want to perform an INSERT operation into an Oracle DB table.

A sample string I want to insert is a HTTP request:

```
a=5&b=hello&date=2016/12/31
```

This string is stored as follows:

```
a=5&b=hello&date=2016%2F12%2F31
```

that is, using URL encoded characters rather than UTF-8 encoded string.

Previously, my string was stored in UTF-8 format as expected.
So, I was able to retrieve and process it using

```
string.split('/')
```

What is the issue? What could be changed in my development environment?
Is this an issue DBMS-side?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
 public static String func(HttpServletRequest request) {

   String date = request.getParameter("date");

   date.split("/");        IT WORKS!!!
}

public static String func(String url_stored_into_DB) {

  String date = getDateFromUrl(url_stored_into_DB);

  date.split("/");        IT DOESN'T WORK!!!
                        since it was stored with %2F
}
```

To store the url into the DB:

```
//HttpServletRequest request comes in to the server
String url = request.toString().substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (URL) VALUES (?)");
stmt.setString(1, url);
stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: The second string just looks encoded as what you would see in a browser URL.  Can you show us the relevant Java code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When the HTTP request comes in to the server, everything is OK: for example, I'm able to get the date parameter and use the split function over it. If I store the url into the database, it will be stored with the escape characters, so the split function will not work

Comment: Show the code which saves to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to split a text string that contains no '/' characters using the '/' character. Of course it doesn't work. Why do I say your string contains no '/' characters? *Because it is URL encoded.* The purpose of URL encoding is to make sure the string doesn't contain various characters that have meaning in URLs.

You need to URL decode it first. Something like this should do the trick.

```
 String date = getDateFromUrl(url_stored_into_DB);
 date = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(date, "UTF-8");

 date.split ("/");
```